# Finding real second order polynomial from a complex polynomial

Tags: calculus, polynomials

So I have the equation $z^4-z^2+1=0$ I've found the complex first order polynomial. But I don't quite know how to find the second order real polynomial and I'm supposed to get $2$ real polynomials. But I only got one.

I tried by setting $z=x+iy$ where $x,y\in R$ and took the $Re(z^4-z^2+1)$

But I only got $x^2-y^2+1=0$ and I havae no clue where to get the second one.

Comment: Please explain what you're talking about when you say "I've found the complex first order polynomial." What are you trying to do, anyhow?

Comment: And why do you have a calculus tag on this??!!

Comment: Do you mean you want to factor the polynomials $z^4-z^2+1$ into two quadratic polynomials with real coefficients? If that is the case, $z^4 - z^2 + 1 = (z^2+1)^2 - 3z^2 = \cdots $